# c# - adding listBox data using list<Object>

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, datasource

I want to populate my `ListBox` by a list of objects  with properties , and I want to know how to define the `listbox` to display a certain property within this object which is some text,
and the other is the name of methods to be invoked while the listBox Items are clicked (SelectIndexChanged)

Comment: Instead of using a list of dictionaries try using observable collection.Refer this [link](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.in/2011/07/binding-observablecollection-to-listbox.html) for binding an observable collection to listbox.

Comment: Why is this a list of dictionaries instead of just a dictionary, or a list of key/value pairs?

Comment: I have used this technique in java and it worked, dont know in c#!
I myself see it complex , but dont know any other idea, if there is a good , better idea , i'll use it

Comment: OK @Naren , but mine is c# and your link uses WPF, and DataContext is WPF , and I cant manupulate design of my Listview tag

Comment: Can the Dictionary inside the List have multiple entries, or is it always just one?

Comment: it can has more than one , but how to bind ?! that is the issue

Comment: The problem is that the question does not make sense. A listbox only has one level of depth, it's a straight list. A list of dictionaries has two levels of depth. You should clearly explain what you expect to happen with an example that has multiple values in one of the dictionaries.

Comment: @Jon what I Excactly want to to is : I want to invoke different methods in each individual select (specific method of specific listBox item) , so I here want to display a text in front face and while clicking call its method which returns a string

Comment: @rabarkareem: I cannot make any sense of that at all.

Comment: Yeah same here, how should the listbox handle the muliple entries inside the dictionary?!? Listbox only does 1 entry per List entry, you could do your own Dictionary and overwrite the ToString to display additional information, but the listbox wont display all dictionary entries within the listbox, just 1 line for each list entry, not multiple based on the dictionary within. Could you explain it more in your real life application, I think it all can be solved with a list holding a class, but not sure...

Comment: hhhhhhh i'm sorry @Jon, I've got maze with this also , 
@RandRandom as you know listbox has `selectedIndex` and `Selecteditem` 
in Displayed Item I display a text , but bihind this text i want to create `selectedValue`to put a method name to be invoked in listItem click, thats it

Comment: Its easy to do this, but again maybe you didnt understand me and thats the main problem - do you NEED to have a List that holds an array/collection/dictionary of objects or is sufficient if it holds only 1 object, so to sum it up List<string> or List<string[]> ?!? If you only need an single object you can just create a class and do a list of these, this class can hold anything methods/properties what ever you wish... (not limited to only 2 properties - as in a keyvaluepair<string, string>) - Array or no array inside a list what shall it be?!?

Comment: No I want only to hold one object which has variety of variables , no an array

Comment: Good to know. :) Please edit your question and make it clear that you only need a List of objects with properties and you want to know how to define the listbox to display a certain property within the object, and maybe ask about how to call diferent methods based on a string property within this object (if you dont know how to do this). To lazy to write a full qualified answer right now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create a listbox, with given height/width and top/left
            var lstBox = new ListBox
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 300,
                Top = 10,
                Left = 10
            };

            //Add the listbox to your form
            this.Controls.Add(lstBox);

            //Create a list of your customclass
            var listCustomClass = new List<CustomClass>();

            //Populate the list with values
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                //create an instanze of your customclass
                var customClass = new CustomClass();

                //set properties of your class
                customClass.Name = "Name " + i;
                customClass.Description = "Description " + i;

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    customClass.MethodName = "CallMeBaby";
                else
                    customClass.MethodName = "CallMeBabyWithParameter";

                customClass.RandomProperty1 = "RandomProperty1 " + i;

                //add the newly created customclass into your list
                listCustomClass.Add(customClass);
            }

            //set the listbox to display or value what you need
            lstBox.DisplayMember = "Description"; //Name of a property inside the class CustomClass
            lstBox.ValueMember = "Name"; //Name of a property inside the class CustomClass

            //set the datasource
            lstBox.DataSource = listCustomClass;

            //register the selectedindexchanged event
            lstBox.SelectedIndexChanged += lstBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        private void lstBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get the listbox from the sender
            var lstBox = (sender as ListBox);

            if (lstBox != null)
            {
                //safe cast the selecteditem to your customclass to get full access to any public property with the class definition
                var customClass = lstBox.SelectedItem as CustomClass;

                if (customClass != null)
                {
                    //do what ever you want with the object and its properties
                    var name = customClass.Name;
                    var desription = customClass.Description;
                    var methodName = customClass.MethodName;
                    var randomProperty1 = customClass.RandomProperty1;

                    //call a certain method based on a string within the object
                    if (methodName == "CallMeBaby")
                        CallMeBaby();
                    else if (methodName == "CallMeBabyWithParameter")
                        CallMeBaby(name);
                }
            }
        }

        //declare the methods that are being called
        private void CallMeBaby(string value)
        {
            //Access the parameter and do something
            if (value == "HelloWorld!")
            {
                //Do something...
            }
        }

        //parameterless method to show the possibilities...
        private void CallMeBaby()
        {
            //Do something...
        }


        //define a public class
        public class CustomClass
        {
            //random properties, can be extended to have what ever your need 
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string MethodName { get; set; }
            public string RandomProperty1 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```